# Error When Renaming Lightswitch Data Source Table

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-lightswitch

After renaming a data source table in Lightswitch I get the following runtime exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code>1</code>
    <message xml:lang="en-US">
        &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&lt;ExceptionInfo&gt;&lt;Message&gt;Schema specified is not valid. Errors: &#xD;
        REDCanonicalData.msl(653,10) : error 2007: The Table 'EntityNames' specified as part of this MSL does not exist in MetadataWorkspace.&#xD;
        REDCanonicalData.msl(652,8) : error 2063: At least one property must be mapped in the set mapping for 'EntityNames'.&lt;/Message&gt;&lt;StackTrace&gt;   at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading.DispatcherExtensions.Invoke(IDispatcher dispatcher, Action action)&#xD;
        at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataService`1.LogicInvoke[T](Func`1 f)&#xD;
        at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataService`1.Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.IODataService.LogicInvoke[T](Func`1 f)&#xD;
        at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataServiceQueryProvider.QueryableWrapper`1.ExecuteGeneric[TResult](Expression expression)&#xD;
        at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataServiceQueryProvider.QueryableWrapper`1.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)&#xD;
        at System.Linq.Queryable.LongCount[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)&lt;/StackTrace&gt;&lt;ErrorInfo /&gt;&lt;/ExceptionInfo&gt;
    </message>
</error>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the build process is not automatically checking out the .ssdl file located in the .../Server/GeneratedArtifacts directory of the project. Since the file is not checked out it remains read-only and can not be updated by the build process.

The solution is to go into TFS Source Code Explorer, manually check out the file, and then rebuild the solution.

If you are not using Team Foundation Server for source control then the file may be read-only or you may not have permission to change it.